# Search on MongoDB across concatenated keys in same collection (e.g. firstname + lastname)

Tags: spring, mongodb, kotlin

I'm trying to search MongoDB from Kotlin, across two keys: firstname + lastname concatenated together. I'm starting with just being able to display all documents in the collection, with the additional field, fullname, created, so I can then search on this field.

```
 val aggregation = if (searchKeyList.isNotEmpty()) {
                val concatExpression = "concat(#personalInformation.firstname, ', ', #personalInformation.lastname)"
                val aggregationOperation = Aggregation.project()
                    .andExpression(concatExpression).`as`("fullname")

                newAggregation(UserEntity::class.java, aggregationOperation)
```

This returns only the firstname field of the document, even then the field is strangely empty?

```
{
        "_id": "65900728fea9bea9cf327dd1",
        "personalInformation": {
            "firstname": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "65900734fea9bea9cf327dd2",
        "personalInformation": {
            "firstname": ""
        }
    },
```

Problem is, I can't even create a concatenated field, along with the entire original document. Is this even possible with MongoDB?

***UPDATE***

Following Andrew's help, this works in one DB hit,
As the last step, I do remove the concatenated field (as I used it temporarily only, for the search)

I am intrigued though by how Andrew said MongoDB is not great at this for 5000 documents, and how ElasticSearch or OpenSearch might be better.

**Q.** Are there any guides on how to set this up alongside MongoDB, for performant querying (if the below is going to be slow on 5000 documents)?

```
 // build a dynamic query using the provided keys and concatenated values
        val typedAggregation = if (searchKeyList.isNotEmpty()) {
            val concatExpression = "concat(personalInformation.firstname, ' ', personalInformation.lastname)"
            Aggregation.newAggregation(
                Aggregation.addFields()
                    .addField("fullname")
                    .withValueOfExpression(concatExpression)
                    .build(),
                Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("fullname").regex(searchValue ?: "", "i")),
                Aggregation.project().andExclude("fullname")
            )
        } else {
            // return an empty flow if concatenatedFieldCriteria is empty
            return flowOf()
        }
```

***Note:*** I've hardcoded the two strings, for clarity. They are meant to be passed through dynamically via the variable, searchKeyList, (so you can concatenate any 'n' number of fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know quite what is wrong with your code, but below is my working code.

We search the DB in two hits, first with the name search using an aggregation very like your code, and find a collection of ids.  Then we pass those ids into a `Criteria` and query the database again adding other criteria that the application wants to search by.

```
val query = KQuery()

if (name != null && name.isNotEmpty()) {
    val nameSearchConcat = Aggregation.project()
        .andExpression("concat(givenName, ' ',familyName, '.', knownAs, ' ', familyName)")
        .`as`("nameSearch")

    val match = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("nameSearch").regex(name, "i"))
    val newAggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(nameSearchConcat, match)
    val aggregationResults =
        mongoTemplate.aggregate(newAggregation, "profile", ProfileNameSearchModel::class.java)
    val filteredProfileIds = aggregationResults.mappedResults.map { it.id }
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").`in`(filteredProfileIds))
}

//other conditions here

val results = mongoTemplate.find(query.with(pageable), Profile::class.java)
```

This is not a performant search since weare not using proper text searching with a specialised index, so the Regex essentially does a full Collection scan - however this works well enoughfor 5000 thousand documents.  (We're replacing this feature with a proper free text Search Engine).

Aside from the performance issues with this approach, it is *functionally* limited.  Not only does the system not do automatic stemming of names, but suffers no match if parts of the names are not fully entered.  You can see we have two alternate name fomulations (`givenName familyName` and `knownAs familyName`), but imagine you don't have a `knownAs` or `nickname`, if you have data like this:

| givenName | familyName |
| --- | --- |
| Alexander | Bell |

then this search approach

- matches `Alex`
- matches `alexander`
- matches `alexander bell`
- matches `Bell`
- does not match `Alex Bell`
- does not match `A Bell`

Comment: Thanks! I’ll take a look at this again tonight. I was trying to concatenate the values of keys that are nested, using dot notation. Maybe that was my problem. Still it should work. I also wonder if the search can be done in one DB hit? That would be twice as performant! Also what do you mean you will implement a full text search? How is that better than your search approach above?

Comment: Q:" what do you mean you will implement a full text search?". A: We have moved to using OpenSearch (aka ElasticSearch) alongside Mongo.  This means we have to continuously update OpenSearch when we make changes to the MongoDB which remains the *master*.  A proper search engine like OpenSearch provides far, far greater capabilities for faceted navigation and full text search than you can ever achieve with Mongo or other DB technology.

Comment: Hi Andrew thanks again for responding! I posted my one DB hit solution above, which works - even on partial search strings - so it may not be functionally limited - though the concat will return null, if either of the fields is null (which is a bit silly, by Mongo DB!). Intruiged though if you have any guides on OpenSearch or ElasticSearch, and how to configure this with Mongo Atlas, if that will be more performant on 5000+ document searches.

Comment: You should probably open a new Question for the OpenSearch matter, but in principle since the solution uses a Regex search, Mongo has to inspect every concatenated set of fields on every Document.   Mongo does have a full text feature (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) that works on an index, BUT there can only be one *text* index per collection. If you are using Atlas Search, this has an extended feature to solve that limitation: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/.  [continued...]

Comment: [cont...]  We are not using Atlas, and moreover we wanted to do far more exotic things - a fully-fledged faceted search (think eBay navigation of categories) as well as full text search, so we are using an external search engine.  It is not trivial to keep the search index sync'd to the DB: essentially this is an *application* responsibility (not a *database* one) to update a node in the search index as the application changes the data in the database.  Some will justifiably argue that this is dangerous/brittle.